# How do I fix this warning in android studio? "Monochrome icon is not defined"

Tags: android

I used the UI to add an adaptive icon and I get this error:

> Monochrome icon is not defined  If android:roundIcon and android:icon
> are both in your manifest, you must either remove the reference to
> android:roundIcon if it is not needed; or, supply the monochrome icon
> in the drawable defined by the android:roundIcon and android:icon
> attribute.  For example, if android:roundIcon and android:icon are
> both in the manifest, a launcher might choose to use android:roundIcon
> over android:icon to display the adaptive app icon. Therefore, your
> themed application iconwill not show if your monochrome attribute is
> not also specified in android:roundIcon.  Issue id:
> MonochromeLauncherIcon

This error message is not clear and also not the way to fix it.